# Which state management architecture is better for my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, state-management

Just to preface this, I have never worked with state management architecture before.

The main characteristics the architecture should have are:

- Scaleable
- Manageable/Debuggable relatively easily
- Compatible with asynchronous aspects of other components
- Ideally it should also be simple enough that a beginner can implement it ( Doesn't have to be easy, just *relatively so*.)

The app is going to have large asynchronous database components, but only much smaller parts of that data will be stored locally.

Other than that, there are also going to be (relatively minor) local functions in the app that will change values and the architecture must manage both of these.

I've searched the web, and the two main ones I've come up with are MobX and BLoC.But here is where I'm stuck.I can't decide between the two ( MobX seems more beginner friendly, but BLoC looks like it works better with Flutter and has more guides ).

So what are your suggestions? It can be about these two or any other that I've missed.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the **provider** package for state management within your Flutter app: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

It's very easy to get going with provider, and it's also recommended within the official Flutter docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and see where is goes.